# AWS EC2 CPU Power Not Scaling With CPU Mark Benchmark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have read on various forums that each ECU on an AWS EC2 roughly equates to a 300 - 400 CPU Mark score in the Passmark performance benchmark. When benchmarking some of the smaller instances with a few ECU's this rule has shown to be true.

Recently I have spun up a cr1.8xlarge instance, which has 88 ECU's. Problem is when I run CPU Mark on it I get an overall score of around 8,300. At minimum I was expecting a CPU Mark score of ~26k (88 x 300). I have ran CPU Mark multiple times on more than one cr1.8xlarge instance. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: The CPU used on those instances is dual Intel Xeon E5-2670. Which should be around 26k. Is there anything that may be affecting threading on its runs?

Comment: Nope, nothing else running on the instance. Basically spun up the instance, installed Passmark and ran the test. Nothing else installed.